# Maximizing size of img

Tags: html, css, image, sass, formatting

So, I am working on something and I am trying to create an image tag that is inside another div. The problem is, I write

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container img {

  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <img src='https://www.clarkson.edu/_site_support/background_image_banks/images/tor_images/studcnt_4128800003.jpg' alt='A problem occured'>

</div>
```

But there is still some room before the edge. I also tried to put padding to 0 and margins to 0 but still, nothing.

Comment: Is the margin of the parent 0 as well? Please post a minimal example of your code, don't link to it.

Comment: the body has a margin. If u want the height of the image contain all the remaining spaces, you should use `height: 100vh;`

Comment: @kabanus I did set the margins of the parent. And also, sorry, I edited the post so that it is more minimal.

Comment: @Ron.Basco That doesn't work. It just becomes an image with a height of 100px

Comment: I already tried it to your codepen demo. vh = viewing height. What ever the height of viewport is, it will get the 100% of it and apply to element with vh property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give body margin as 0px;

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. @Guy Blum

Answer (score 0):

Use a reset file or structure in css to set the values to a defined default and not let browsers get that. One of the reset files I've used is from here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ . The body in this case has a margin of 8px and since there is not box-sizing defined it affects the widths. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
body,html{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the float attribute to get rid of the extra room:

```
div img { float: left }
```

But about the size of the image you need to have in mind that if the div's width/height is set as percentage, the inner element's width/height can not be set in percentage.

If you'd like to set the image width/height in percentage, you need to specify the dimensions of the div in pixels.

E.g.

This works:

```
div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But this does not work:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Totally, what you need to handle both parts of your question is something like this:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img {
    float: left; /* or right, whatever you'd rather */
    display: block;
}
```

Though, for a better suggestion, information about the container of the div's needed.